# How can I add 3rd drm plugin on Android?

Tags: cryptography, drm

If I am a Android app developer and I have 3rd drm plugin support android drm framework. How can I add the drm plugin to Android system and register it?

I know that in regular method is add the new plugin to `/system/vendor/lib/mediadrm`, but if not a device provider, impossibly, we can't have the root right to put the plugin into this system folder and register it?

If we add drm in app player, I searched some open source player, I have not found inject point to decrypt sample frame. Such as EXOplayer in android, It has only support DRMFramework in android by mediadrm,
Mediacodec can decrypt sample frame by injected mediacrypto object(mediacrypto is conjunction by mediadrm), but if target system can not support the drm scheme, we can not use it.

Comment: You may get more views with an appropriate android tag.  Is this really about programming?

Answer (score 0):

In a regular Android phone, as an app developer you can't add in a new DRM plugin, as you say.

DRM systems are ultimately just a way to securely get a key from the server side to the client side. The complexity on the server side is generally around deciding who is entitled to the key and making sure the requester is really who they say they are, and that the DRM client on the device is really who it says it is.

On the client side, the device will generally have a secure media player function which takes as input the encrypted video and the key, which it gets from the DRM system. It then decrypts and renders the video directly to the screen.

The client and even the OS is usually not allowed any access to the unencrypted video or to the key for the content - this prevents (or at least makes it harder) for rouge apps to copy content.

If you just need moderate protection and don't want to use an existing DRM system you can just use clearkey - this does not really give much protection but it may be enough for your needs. You can test this simply in a browser using the Shaka player which provides example clearkey configuration here: https://github.com/google/shaka-player/blob/master/docs/tutorials/drm-config.md